# how to extract key value which contain spaces or quotes after key name

Tags: linux, bash

suppose i have file which contain following data like book name and author of and please note that book name not contain any space.For example file.txt as below

```
book1 john
book2 srikar valiya
book3 adi ularam
book4 neina
```

from above script i want just author name so for this i have make following script

```
#!/bin/bash


printf "Auther\n=========\n"


grep book1 file.txt | awk  '{print $2}'
grep book2 file.txt | awk  '{print $2}'
grep book3 file.txt | awk  '{print $2}'
grep book4 file.txt | awk  '{print $2}'
```

which give me output like

```
Author
=========
john
srikar
adi
neina
```

but i want

```
Author
=========
john
srikar valiya
adi  ularam
neina
```

Also one improvement needed in my scripts like i have write 4 `grep` statement  to extract author name(currently only 4 available) but what if more then 100 lines in file and not same pattern of book name in file.(it not good for me check how many line in file and write `grep` as many as lines also `grep` not possible because name contain any pattern)

Any one have idea?

Comment: You can do: `cat file.txt | awk  '{print $2" "$3}'` (in lines with  only first name - the second parameter will be ignored)

Comment: not good solution..what if name contain more then 2 column?

Comment: how many columns it will be (maximum) ? 3 ? 4 ? 5 ? then run it with $1 ... $5

Comment: how many column? not known for me..any 3 or 5 or 100..

Comment: Right... someone with 100 names... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `cut` instead:

```
grep book1 file.txt | cut -d" " --complement -f1
```

Comment: yes it works..but have you any idea when more then 100 lines in files and not have known pattern for name of book?

Comment: @JKB If you're certain that every line in the file contains a book name without spaces followed by the author name, you could say: `cut -d" " --complement -f1 < filename`.

Comment: @devnull I get: `usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]`

Comment: @alfasin You don't seem to be using `cut` that is a part of GNU coreutils.  In that case, you can say `cut -d" " -f2- < filename`

Comment: @devnull yes `cut -d" " --complement -f1 < filename` works it nice solution in one sentence .

Comment: @devnull you're right! mind explaining why it's different on my mac ?

Comment: @alfasin Your mac probably ships with BSD version of `cut` that doesn't support `--complement`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `awk  '{print $2}'` try `cut -d' ' -f2-`

Answer (score 1):

```
i=1
while :; do
    line=$(grep "book$i" input) || break
    name=$(sed 's/[^ ]* //' <<< $line)
    echo "$name"
    let i++
done
```

If you have no idea about the name of the book, but sure that each line contains a book:

```
while read line; do
    name=$(sed 's/[^ ]* //' <<< $line)
    echo "$name"
done < input
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk should do the trick:

```
awk '{$1=""; sub(/^ */, "");}1' file
john
srikar valiya
adi ularam
neina
```